# AdaptiveTrigger in secondary Page

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, win-universal-app

I'm trying to build an application where the main page only contais a simple menu where the menu options load other pages on another `Frame`. Something like this:

```
<Page>
    <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups />
        <SplitView>
            <SpliView.Pane> menu items </SplitView.Pane>
            <Frame />
        </SplitView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I have created a `VisualStateManager` with some `AdaptiveTriggers` on the main page to adjust the menu size and it all works as it should.

My problem is when I try the same on a page that gets loaded inside the `Frame`. Everything works as it should except for the `AdaptiveTriggers`: the controls on the page don't get *adapted* as the window size changes.

**SOLVED:**

I was trying to change controls declared inside a `DataTemplate`. Once I changed the template into a `UserControl` everything worked as expected.

Comment: Can you show the exact XAML example of what you tried and what is not working?

Comment: I have already solved my problem: I was trying to change controls declared inside a `DataTemplate`. Once I changed the template into a `UserControl` everything worked as expected.